# biometric login on php / flash app

Tags: php, security, drupal, fingerprint, biometrics

i have a biometric fingerprint usb device, is there a way to integrate that kind of security with php site / drupal site? so user need to login and give his finger print in order to login?

Comment: lmao. Not too sure what I was thinking. Comment withdrawn.

Comment: May be http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html will be helping as its APIs are javascript to connect the biometric device

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

With your PHP website on a remote server and your USB device on the clients side you would need some kind of interaction between the 2.

The easiest way would be to embed Java into your website to access your USB device, get the data, and pass it on to your website.

This would still need you to have some kind of API or driver for your device, so you can integrate it to your own app. Check the publisher of that USB product for more information; if they actually provide something like that.

Your browser with JavaScript alone will not be able to access your device. Thus, its more of a hassle than a simple extension of your PHP drupal site.